# Python, all possible combinations of numbers between 2 lists

Tags: python, list, combinations

I'm new to python and I would like some guidance with a problem I'm having.

Let's say you have two lists, with same length and filled with numbers:

```
x=[0,1,2,3]
y=[0,4,5,6]
```

How can Python calculate the numbers between the numbers in the list at the same position?
So for this example.

```
[0,1,2,3]
[0,2,2,3]
[0,3,2,3]
[0,4,2,3]
[0,1,3,3]
...
```

I hoped someone with more experience would have some insight in this matter.

Comment: Can you clarify what the "numbers between the numbers in the list at the same position" means?

Comment: Do you need the numbers between only at each position, or also all combinations? In your example, do you need `[0,4,3,5]`

Comment: So, in your example, the result would have 4**3 entries?

Comment: These numbers are a Golomb ruler and in need to find the prefect one so that's why I need to check all different combinations.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
x=[0,1,2]
y=[0,4,5]

from itertools import product

for lst in product(*(range(a, b+1) for a, b in zip(x, y))):
    print(lst)
#>>> (0, 1, 2)
#>>> (0, 1, 3)
#>>> (0, 1, 4)
#>>> (0, 1, 5)
#>>> (0, 2, 2)
#>>> (0, 2, 3)
#>>> (0, 2, 4)
#>>> (0, 2, 5)
#>>> (0, 3, 2)
#>>> (0, 3, 3)
#>>> (0, 3, 4)
#>>> (0, 3, 5)
#>>> (0, 4, 2)
#>>> (0, 4, 3)
#>>> (0, 4, 4)
#>>> (0, 4, 5)
```

`zip` takes the `x` and `y` and produces (in this case) `[(0, 0), (1, 4), (2, 5)]`.

The `for a, b in` takes each pair and unpacks it into `a` and `b`, so for the second `a = 1` and `b = 4`.

Then a `range` is made for each. It is `range(a, b+1)` because the last item in the range is dropped.

You then have an iterable of ranges:

```
[ range(0, 1), range(1, 5), range(2, 6) ]
```

`product` takes some iterables and makes an iterable of all the possible combinations. So you "unpack" the iterables with the "*" operator, so `product` is called like

```
product(*[ range(0, 1), range(1, 5), range(2, 6) ])
```

which is equivalent to

```
product(range(0, 1), range(1, 5), range(2, 6))
```

and produces the result.

Comment: Yes that's just what I need. Thank you very much!